# Why I'm getting empty json result

Tags: android, json, node.js

I'm trying to send post message with 2 fields (user and pass).

The node.js which handle the post looks (just the print code, not all the function):

```
app.post('/login.html', function (req, res) {

    log.info("Got: " , req.body);
    userName = req.body.name;
    pass = req.body.pass;
}
```

the android app looks:

```
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
mRequestQueue.start();

JsonPost(mRequestQueue);
```

The JsonPost method looks:

```
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.json_get_url);
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

try {
    // adding some keys
    jsonParams.put("name", "root");
    jsonParams.put("pass", "123456");

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

// Initialize a new JsonObjectRequest instance
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
        }
    }
)
```

I'm getting `{}` (empty json outputs in the node.js: GOT: {})

I looked at this post: (but didn't found the answer)
[Getting Empty JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416044/getting-empty-json-response)

Why I'm getting empty json body, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Your node.js post handler does nothing to send back a response. So why would there be some?

Comment: just for debugging (there is response, but I didn't show it)

Comment: Well, you asked "Why I'm getting empty json result" and then posted some code that does not generate a response ...

Comment: I update the Q.

Comment: JsonPost(mRequestQueue);   How the mRequestQueue used in function? can not see mRequestQueue in your posted codes.

Comment: Have you installed body-parser?

Comment: yes, I installed it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your posted codes is incomplete, but we should use below line:

```
mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

so please check it.